# Export KML from GeoJSON in QGIS and coordinates change?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, kml, geojson

I'm very new in this area. I have a geojson vector layer file, with coordinates like

```
{ "type": "Feature",  "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 487677.2993499999866, 112018.26101 ] } },
```

I open it in QGIS, I change the default SRC of the couche and from the project to match with my data (EPSG:4149).

When I export then this in KML, I have those coordinates for the same point:

```
  <Placemark>
          <Point><coordinates>-122.700650000013411,112018.26101</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
```

I don't understand why the first coordinate changes. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

`change the default SRC` is the reason for the misplacement.

If you want lat/lon coordinates, turn that back to the original value, and save the layer to a different file name and CRS EPSG:4326 using `Rightclick -> Save As...`

Comment: Hello,Thank you very much but that don't help me: I've exactly the same coordinate change when I keep the original values (EPSG:4236).

Comment: Your coordinates seem to be in meters, while KML needs them in degrees. The geojson file should have a CRS definition. If not, you have to set it in QGIS. `EPSG:21781 CH1903/LV03` may be the right one if the point should be west of Genève.